# Meteor: importing whole module doesn't work

Tags: javascript, meteor, import, module

I am trying to make my Meteor code ES6 compatible. I had a file called `/both/global.js` containing functions and constants that I wanted to be accessible globally. For ES6 purposes, I moved it to `/both/imports/global.js` and prefaced all the functions and constants with `export const`.

I haven't changed the whole directory structure yet. The template javascript files are still in `/client/controller/`. I have added to them `import` statements for the exported functions and constants. When I write the import statements in the form:

`import { fn1, fn2, ... } from '../../both/imports/global.js';`

they work fine.

I would rather import all the functions and constants with a single:

`import from '../../both/imports/global.js';`

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the way imports and exports work.

What you need is

`import * from '/both/imports/global.js'`

Alternatively...

`import something from '/both/imports/global.js'`

Will look for the `default` export, and assign it to the variable called `something`.

`import { fn1, fn2, ... } ...`

Will import the named variables into your namespace

Another way is to do this:

`import globalFunctions from '/both/imports/global.js'`

Then your functions are callable like this:

`globalFunctions.fn1()
globalFunctions.fn2()`

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what does `import from '../../both/imports/global.js';` do, then?

Comment: that will do nothing

Comment: @Mikkel last one should probably have been `import * as globalFunctions from 'path'`, otherwise you still look only for the default export.

Comment: Forgot about that one, added it